# Elementor Widget Folder - WordPress

Tags: wordpress, elementor

Does anyone know where Elementor saves its widgets? I'm looking for inside the Elementor plugin directory, but I can't find it.

I'm a newby developing plugins and widgets for WordPress

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Check in `wp-content\plugins\elementor\includes\widgets` folder

Comment: Ok! I've already put the widget code in. The problem is my widget is not appearing on the widget panel now. I have followed the official boilerplate given by Elementor and I think that everything is ok...

Comment: Are you including your widget as plugin?